# Increasing the number of iterations in the excel solver

Tags: microsoft-excel

Im having a problem with the solver in excel when Im using two variables that needs to be fitted. Often the solver completely ignores one of the variables and just fits the first variable unless the second variable is a good guess.

Its just fitting a second order equation to two or more measurement points so its ridiculous that excel even fail.

How can I increase the number of iterations the solver tries? Ive played around with the convergence option but it doesn't help.

Comment: Do you know something about Operations Research principles or what your problem mathematical model would look like? Normally Excel solver is random and unless you have a linear problem you'll get just a good guess, no matter how many iterations you put. If you want I can make a full answer about how to change parameters in the solver